# How can i perform an event after ajax content loads in a div using jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am developing a scrolling feed content, i have successfully gotten the feed content to display inside a div. Now i want each feed item to scroll. So i use cycle plugin, but cycle plugin doesn't detect the tag specified that holds the content from scrolling.

See my complete code here http://jsfiddle.net/guru01/LxBHX/

```
$('#img').load(function() {
            $('.feedEkList').cycle({
                fx:     'scrollUp', 
                timeout: 6000, 
                delay:  -2000
            });
        });
});
```

Comment: Read the jQuery docs on using the success: callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Check here for Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LxBHX/3/)**

it should be like this

```
jQuery(window).load(function () {
```

Instead of below

```
$('#img').load(function() {
```